# Warning whenever i run python in my command prompt ( i have installed anaconda latest version on my windows 8.1 os)

Tags: python, anaconda

Whenever I enter python in my command prompt I get a warning like this below. Whenever I use `conda activate base` And then enter python, I get no warning. But I have seen many people just writing Python like I just entered in my command prompt and they get no warning. How can I remove this warning?

How can I get it right?

This is the link to the screenshot that I got during entering the command:

[image: 1]

Comment: did you installed python separately before installing anaconda

Comment: yes, but then i uninstalled it first. Then i installed anaconda

Comment: did you set environment variable for anaconda

Comment: yes, i choose the option to add path while installing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's working, haha.

- Firstly, the ">>>" alone means that you are in a Python environment within the interpreter.

Although, it might also mean that you didn't install Python correctly.